# Is Open LDAP meant to work with the passwd command for Linux?

Tags: opensuse, password, ldap

I've implemented an Open LDAP server in OpenSuSE 11.2 via the YaST GUI.  I'm having success logging in from the local machine and other machines via LDAP.  I am able to change LDAP user passwords via

`passwd`

on the command line.  However, I cannot do anything else through the command line, such as 
`passwd -e username`.
I get the following error

> Authentication failure. 
>   LDAP information update failed: Operations error
>   Error while changing password expiry information.

The same goes for any other arguments regarding password expiry or for locking accounts via `-l`.
Is this simply a limitation of the LDAP server, or do I have an incorrect configuration?

Answer (score 9):

`passwd` just uses PAM. Configure PAM to send password changes to LDAP.

Add the following to `/etc/pam.d/common-password`

```
password   sufficient pam_ldap.so try_first_pass
password   required   pam_unix.so nullok obscure min=4 max=8 md5 try_first_pass
```

This assumes that you've already configured LDAP to allow the necessary writes and the only thing lacking is the PAM set up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `passwd` command has plug-ins to manage anything other than the local password database (`/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow`). You need to use a separate tools like `yppasswd` for NIS or `ldappasswd` for LDAP.